# Create Environment Variable file in Snowflake UI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-codepipeline, snowflake-schema, aws-codecommit, snowflake-connector

How can I specify environment variable in Snowflake UI, so that when I deploy my code from one tenant to another, i need not to update environment keyword in code; i am using AWS Codecommit.
Like -
Create table database$env.schema.table;

A .sql file will be there in AWS Codecommit, And inside that file somewhere we need to mention a Environmental variable which needs to pickup the Dev,Qa and Prod.
The code inside the .sql file needs to be executed through AWS Codepipeline, and then it should reflect in Snowflake UI.

Many Thanks !

Comment: When you say “between tenants” do you mean between different Snowflake accounts or within the same Snowflake account?

Comment: Our scenario is, A .sql file will be there in AWS Codecommit, And inside that file somewhere we need to mention a Environmental variable which needs to pickup the Dev,Qa and Prod.
The code inside the .sql file needs to be executed through AWS Codepipeline, and then it should reflect in Snowflake UI... how we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a user account, some of the repeated values can be set up as a variable. This article will describe the usage of variable in creating user account via Snowflake UI and SnowSQL.

In some cases, it is desirable to combine text and variable, this can be achieved in SnowSQL only.

More Details:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-variable-when-creating-user-account-in-Snowflake-UI-and-SnowSQL

Comment: Our scenario is, A .sql file will be there in AWS Codecommit, And inside that file somewhere we need to mention a Environmental variable which needs to pickup the Dev,Qa and Prod.
The code inside the .sql file needs to be executed through AWS Codepipeline, and then it should reflect in Snowflake UI... how we can achieve this ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/11/03/snowflake-dataOps.html